# Web service client using wsdl2java and Spring

Tags: java, spring, web-services, cxf

I would like my Spring MVC based app to consume a web service. 
Only thing I know about the service is it's WSDL.

I'm using [this example from W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL) for testing purposes.

I'm able to generate client's java artifacts through WSDL2Java utility from CXF. It gives me some interfaces and their implementations and some usage example in main method (but it's not much help for this purpose).

What configuration do I have to do in my app to simply integrate this client? I would prefer XML conf aproach.

Used versions are:

- CXF 2.7.10
- Spring 3.2.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CXF has a `<jaxws:client />` element that is used for configuring the client.

You specify an `@WebService` annotated Interface as the `serviceClass` property, and the endpoint URL as the `address` property.  For example, assuming wsdl2java generated `com.w3schools.webservices.TempConvertSoap`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws
          http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

    <jaxws:client id="tempconvertClient"
                  serviceClass="com.w3schools.webservices.TempConvertSoap"
                  address="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx" />
</beans>
```

You can inject the `tempconvertClient` bean as `com.w3schools.webservices.TempConvertSoap`, and use it to make your service calls.

For more information, see the CXF [JAX-WS Configuration](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-ws-configuration.html) documentation.

Comment: Thank you for clarification, I'll give it a try ASAP. Of course I have found this article before, but I was a bit confused from what this aproache will result in. Never mind my fault.